# Rewrite View Header into first views-row

Tags: 7, views, theming

I need to rewrite/move the header of one View into the first row of that View.

Current View output:

```
<div class="view">
    <div class="view-header">view header text</div>
    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-2">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-3">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-4">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-5">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-6">output</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
<div class="view">
    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1">view header text</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-2">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-3">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-4">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-5">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-6">output</div>
        <div class="views-row views-row-7">output</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can this be accomplished?

The views-row divs are then displayed inline in a responsive flex grid, so that each views-row div has the same height as its neighbor divs on that same row. Each views-row div is 25% width, so they are displayed in 4 columns (4 divs across the page, with subsequent divs wrapping in 4 additional columns below as needed).

I need the header to be part of that flex grid. I tried applying the flex grid markup to the "view-header" div and the "view-content" div, but it does not provide the desired result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hook_views_post_execute()` or `hook_views_pre_render()` hooks. Provide you just an example, so you have to add validations and change format of $item variable youself, it depends of your views configuration.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
 */
function mymodule_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  $item = (object) array('node_title' => $view->header['area']->options['content']);
  array_unshift($view->result, $item);
}
```